# iOS-WCF non-primitive type issue

Tags: c#, ios, wcf, xamarin, primitive-types

I am developing an app on xamarin.ios. I have a wcf service that ios app connects. I would like to pass stream or byte[] or my custom class to wcf function, but an exception is occur.

So, I tried to use object as parameter, it doesnt work.. After that I converted byte[] to string, it doesnt work either, I think string is long.. Because when I try simple string (like string a ="hello") it works, but converting from byte arr to string, its very long (because I am converting file stream)..

I am thinking to solve it for a while but havent found out a solution yet.

here is the wcf part

```
     public string StartCreateDocument(WebServiceLogin login, string data, string docName)
    {

         //....
    }
```

and ios side

```
           MyService service = new MyService();
       //     string data = Convert.ToBase64String(byteimg);

                string data = BitConverter.ToString(byteimg);

            service.StartCreateDocumentCompleted += service_StartCreateDocumentCompleted;
                service.StartCreateDocumentAsync(BaseService.Login,data,"Iphone_Image1");
```

I put a break point  in the function of the wcf service, but it doesnt trigger..

and service_startcreatedocumentcompleted event is triggered. and result is

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

i hope that i am clear..

Comment: Please post the `InnerException` of the `TargetInvocationException`.

Comment: @nvoigt, thank you for your reply, xamarin.ios hasnt detailed exception, I called the method normally (not async) and i got this exception. System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 413: RequestEntityTooLarge  .. I think I should change some size on wcf?